# Python not editing XML while using etree

Tags: python, xml

I am using an XML document to keep track of user information, in python. I was doing some tests in IDLE, but for some reason the XML is not being edited. I looked all over the python docs and I couldn't find the issue at all. Here is what I was typing:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('./usrData.xml')
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> root.tag
meritTracker
```

Up until this part, everything was working fine. I know it read the right document, because it showed the right tag. But then:

```
>>>newElement = ET.Element('Name')
>>>ET.SubElement(root, newElement)
<Element <Element 'Name' at 0x1022119f0> at 0x102211a48>
```

The XML Doc doesn't change at all. 
I then reset IDLE, and did this:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('./usrData.xml')
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> root.tag
meritTracker 
>>>newElement = ET.Element('Name')
>>>root.append(newElement)
>>>root.getchildren()
```

Still nothing. 
Then I tried the long way around:

```
>>> file = open('./usrData.xml','r+')
>>> tree = ET.parse(file)
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> root.append(ET.Element('Name'))
>>> root.getchildren()
[<Element 'Name' at 0x101756680>]
```

However, the XML still did not change! How can I fix this?

Note: Im running Python 3.3 on Mac OS X 10.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write your output back to the file:

```
tree.write('output.xml')
```

Comment: Do I write it out after every change or only when the program is completed? In other words, does Python store the changes in local memory?

Comment: @elder4222 no just when the program is completed, you should be finished editing your tree before you need to use it again. Is that not the case here?

Comment: yes, that is the case. I was just confirming. Thanks for all your help guys!